# Is there a way to solve integral containing square of incomplete gamma function?

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Is there a way to solve such an integral: $$\int\frac{\Gamma(a,x)^2}{x^2}dx$$ in terms of known functions? The free online version of the WolframAlpha tool does not provide any solution for it. For the function without square of the incomplete gamma function $$\int\frac{\Gamma(a,x)}{x^2}dx$$ the tool gives solution in terms of incomplete gamma function itself $$\Gamma(a-1,x)-\frac{\Gamma(a,x)}{x}$$Could a similar solution exist for the first equation above where the square of the incomplete gamma function is used under integral?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes, with Mathematica I have: $$\int \frac{\Gamma (a,x)^2}{x^2} \, dx=-\frac{2 e^{-x} x^{-1+a} \Gamma (a,x)}{-1+a}+\frac{\Gamma
   (a,x)^2}{-1+a}+\frac{\Gamma (a,x)^2}{(-1+a) x}-\frac{a \Gamma (a,x)^2}{(-1+a) x}+\frac{2^{2-2 a} \Gamma (-1+2
   a,2 x)}{-1+a}$$

Comment: Thanks Mariusz! This is exactly I was looking for. I used WolframAlpha online tool which din not provide any solution and was wondering if such could exist.